# Show that the function $d$ defines a metric on $\mathbb Z$.

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, divisibility, problem-solving

Define $d$ on $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ by,

$d(x,y)=0 $ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=m^{-1}$,where $m$ is the largest positive integer such that $10^{m-1}$ divides $(x-y)$.

Show that the function defines a metric on $\mathbb Z$.
I am having problem with the triangle inequality.Can someone please help me?

Comment: It is called the 10-adic distance ; see the beginning of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number.

Comment: @JeanMarie Tell me more on this and by the wat $p$ is prime here,but $10$ is not a prime.So,what does $10$-adic mean?

Comment: You have seen that in the introduction to the article, they say in substance "10 is not prime but we are going to explain p-adic distance with p=10 because we are more familiar with base 10". **Intuitively :** a 10adic number is a number which has a finit number of digits to the right of the point and an infinite number to the left ! Which may hurt intuition but makes sense for the operations of addition and multiplication (we can add or multiply such numbers with usual algorithms):

Comment: see as well p. 4 of this document : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.08835.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either $x=y$ or $y=z$, then the triangle inequality is clear. Otherwise, $d(x,y)$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$, where $n$ is the number of common trailing digits of $x$ and $y$, assuming that they have the same sign. Ditto for $d(x,z)$ and $d(y,z)$.

Now, suppose that $x$ and $y$ have $m$ common trailing digits, and $y$ and $z$ have $n$ common trailing digits. If $m=n$, then $x$ and $z$ would have at least $n$ common trailing digits, let's say $p$. Then, $d(x,z)=\frac{1}{p+1} \le \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Otherwise, $x$ and $z$ would have $p:=\min(m,n)$ common trailing digits, and then $d(x,z)=\frac{1}{p+1}=\max(\frac{1}{m+1}, \frac{1}{n+1})=\max(d(x,y),d(y,z))$.

Hence, we have an ultrametric space.

Comment: common trailing digit means?

Comment: [+1] The important keyword here is "ultrametric" distance.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar "Common trailing digits" means the shared digits at the end of the numbers. The description does not work, however, if one of the numbers is positive and the other is negative; instead, one needs to add the absolute values and then find the number of trailing zeros in the result.